# Delete records from 2 tables in join with Django ORM

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and have 2 tables and I want to delete records from the join.

These are simplified model definitions:

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModelA(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.OneToOneField(
        MyModelA, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint=False
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

If I used `SQL`, I could write a `DELETE` statement with a join, which would delete all records that are returned by the join like this:

```sql
DELETE a, b 
FROM mymodela AS a
INNER JOIN mymodelb AS b
ON a.id = b.modela_id
WHERE a.created < '<some date>'
```

I would like to use the Django ORM and the `delete()` method.

I could easily write the `SELECT` equivalent using:

```py
MyModelA.objects.filter(mymodelb__isnull=False)
    .filter(created__lt=<some date>)
    .select_related("mymodelb")
```

However, when I chain the `delete()`, only records in `MyModelA` are deleted and the resulting `SQL`-query is something like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM mymodela WHERE mymodela.id IN (<LIST OF IDs in JOIN>)
```

I could of course use a different `on_delete` action or get the list of ids and delete the records table by table, but I would like to know: is it possible to get a `DELETE a, b FROM...` statement as shown above?